# What's the maximum size of a image to send using MQTT

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm trying to send some images using MQTT in two R-pi.
I wonder what's the maximum size of image to send.
I think 1MB is the maximum size however, 26.5KB image could not be sended.
Please give an answer of my question thank you.

Comment: https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/sending-and-receiving-pictures-from-a-raspberry-pi-via-mqtt/

Comment: Please include your python code in the question

Answer (score 5):

MQTT doc Mosquito:

**message_size_limit limit**

> This option sets the maximum publish payload size that the broker will
>   allow. Received messages that exceed this size will not be accepted by
>   the broker. The default value is 0, which means that all valid MQTT
>   messages are accepted. MQTT imposes a maximum payload size of
>   268435455 bytes.

From:

https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html

Comment: Which is effectively 256mb (taken from the MQTT spec http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718023)